# Receiving issues with Android.Volley.Servererror when logcatting a volley attempt

Tags: retrofit2, jsoup, android-volley

I am trying to follow a tutorial that will build a very basic app that pulls a JSON from a server, I have been waylaid due to problems; I'm having no end of problems trying to pull from the server

I have been looking into a network issue with several apps using dependencies by Retrofit and Volley, the problem lies within both as actual devices and emulator, both with Retrofit and Volley by Google. Which tells me that there's something in my code the server does not like

The code is simply jumping to OnFailure in code and, in production, I just get 'Fail to get data' or something similar.I couldn't figure out why. This has been going on for a few days, and I have checked my phone, my emulator and my network, all seems ok and the issue is still outstanding

I found this post which was extremely helpful in introducing Jsoup for faultfinding purposes.
[Android Volley no Response from StringRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887160/android-volley-no-response-from-stringrequest)

I have now managed to run a logcat and found issue com.android.volley.ServerError, which I beleive is linked to Nulls. I dont know where to go from here as Ive been using code that has been proven to have worked on someone elses device. Can someone please help heres my code
Here is my code

```
  '''
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
                Surface(
                    // on below line we are specifying modifier and color for our app
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {

                    // on below line we are specifying theme as scaffold.
                    Scaffold(

                        // in scaffold we are specifying top bar.
                        topBar = {

                            // inside top bar we are specifying background color.
                            TopAppBar(backgroundColor = Green,
                                // along with that we are specifying title for our top bar.
                                title = {
                                    // in the top bar we are specifying tile as a text
                                    Text(

                                        // on below line we are specifying
                                        // text to display in top app bar.
                                        text = "JSON Parsing in Android",

                                        // on below line we are specifying
                                        // modifier to fill max width.
                                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),

                                        // on below line we are
                                        // specifying text alignment.
                                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,

                                        // on below line we are
                                        // specifying color for our text.
                                        color = Color.White
                                    )
                                })
                        }) {
                        // on below line we are display list view
                        // method to display our list view.
                        displayListView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


fun parseJSONArray(courseList: MutableList<String>, ctx: Context) {

    val url = "http://www.fringeb7.co.il/";
    val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx)
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,
        { response ->
            try {
                val response_utf8 =
                    URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(response, "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                val doc : org.jsoup.nodes.Document = Jsoup.parse(response_utf8)
                Log.d("logr=", "title = " + doc.title())
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,Log.d("logr=", "title = " + doc.title()).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    ) { error ->
        error.printStackTrace()
        Log.d("log2=", error.toString())
        //requestQueue.stop();
    }
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
    requestQueue.start()
}

@Composable
fun displayListView() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // on below line we are creating and
    // initializing our array list
    val courseList = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }
    parseJSONArray(courseList, context)

    // on the below line we are creating a
             // lazy column for displaying a list view.
             // on below line we are calling lazy column
            // for displaying lstview.
             LazyColumn {
            // on below line we are populating
            // items for listview.
                items(courseList) { language ->
                // on below line we are specifying ui for each item of list view.
                // we are specifying a simple text for each item of our list view.
                Text(language, modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp))
                // on below line we are specifying
                // divider for each list item
               Divider()
            }
        }
   
    }
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this in the end while looking into a separate issue. It seems that I was not paying enough attention to resolving the issue using Logcat and expecting a Toast error message to give me all the information I needed. When using Logcat I am getting responses clearly.
The code this gentleman uses is halfway down the page.

[https://sebhastian.com/android-studio-log-d/#:~:text=the%20command%20line.-,The%20Log.,to%20display%20on%20the%20Logcat](https://sebhastian.com/android-studio-log-d/#:%7E:text=the%20command%20line.-,The%20Log.,to%20display%20on%20the%20Logcat)

this gentleman provides the answer that I have been looking for
'''
@Composable
val queue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LocalContext.current)
val url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"

```
    val stringRequest = JsonArrayRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        { response -> Log.d("MainActivity", "Response is: " + response.toString()) }
    ) { error -> Log.e("MainActivity", "Request error: " + error.toString()) }
    queue.add(stringRequest)}
'''
```